# PHP Xampp POST Content-Length

Tags: php, angular, slim

Hi and thank you for reading this.

I am faced with the following error when I POST pdf file to the server:

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 9353594 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Unexpected data in output buffer. Maybe you have characters before an opening finalize(Object(Slim\Http\Response)) #1 D:\1.WORK\CreditSmart\AngularProjects\creditcover_backend\public\index.php(32): Slim\App->run() #2 {main} thrown in D:\1.WORK\CreditSmart\AngularProjects\creditcover_backend\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php on line 625

I use Slim PHP and I have set the `post_max_size=5000M` and also `upload_max_filesize=20000M` but I still get the error. Why is that?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Have you called phpinfo() or something to _verify_ the settings you tried to make, actually took effect?

Comment: already restart webserver?

Answer (score 0):

In phpinfo check which php.ini is used and edit the correct php.ini as in the phpinfo and set the following value or something desired bigger value. 8388608 bytes is 8M, the default limit in PHP. Update your post_max_size in php.ini to a larger value.

```
upload_max_filesize = 1000M; <-- as per your need
post_max_size = 1000M; <-- as per your need
```

Restart your webserver and see first if value has been changed or not. If value is changed then you should not have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. On my windows I have PHP7 installed. My Xampp also has PHP but it is not the one my system uses. I just had to configure the correct PHP config file. Now everything works fine.